# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8551: bind: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm trying to create three nodes with one private chain.

node1 is successfully created.
But node2 and node3 showing the following error.

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8551: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

command used in node1

```
geth --networkid 15 --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.port "8549" --http.api "web3,net,eth,admin,personal" --http.corsdomain "*" --datadir nodedata0 --ipcdisable --allow-insecure-unlock --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs console
```

command used in node2

```
geth --http --http.port 8550 --nodiscover --datadir  "./nodedata1"  --port 30304 --http.api "web3,net,eth,admin,personal" --http.corsdomain "*" --networkid 15 --ipcdisable --allow-insecure-unlock --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs console
```

command use in node3

```
geth --http --http.port 8552 --nodiscover --datadir  "./nodedata2"  --port 30307 --http.api "web3,net,eth,admin,personal" --http.corsdomain "*" --networkid 15 --ipcdisable console
```

Please give some advance kindly, thanks a lot.

Comment: See here [--authrpc.port](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/136315/109179)

Comment: Thanks for comment, but it's not work when i trying to set up three nodes.

Comment: what's ur new commands?

Answer (score 1):

Using `--authrpc.port` should work, I tried with two nodes so the config was `--authrpc.port 8551` and `--authrpc.port 8552`. Based on @season comment.